# How to use if(DEBUG) in java in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

I know I'm throwing a pretty stupid question, but I promise I did try to search around the settings and around google and the webs and no luck, so I guess I should just ask.

I saw in quite a few open-source projects the following line:

```
if(DEBUG){
    //  do some logging
}
```

I perfectly understand what the line is doing, I just can't seem to repeat it.
There's no declaration of `boolean DEBUG;` anywhere in the code, and I couldn't figure out a place on the project properties to define a system wide variable to be replaced on the compiling (into byte code). And as far as I know, if it's a reference to a class constant it was supposed to be `Log.DEBUG` or something similar.

Can anyone solve this mystery for me?
thanks.

Comment: Did you look in your imports to see if it was there? It could be a static import, which would explain why it is not declared in the source code.

Comment: I'm guessing they're all inheriting from some class that does have the constant defined, probably initializing it from some settings file...

Comment: If you're using Eclipse: Put the cursor on the word `DEBUG` and press F3. It should jump to the declaration of `DEBUG`.

Comment: @Jesper - Taught me something new. I normally use `ctrl+click` which does the same thing, but always good to learn another way =)

Comment: It was mostly on GitHub or google.code, but it's for Android so I'm 95% sure it was on Eclipse. I'm searching for some of those projects so I can post here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You really should look at the import section of the class.

It is probably a [static import](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/static-import.html), like this :

---

A.java

```
public class A {
    public static boolean DEBUG = false;
}
```

---

B.java

```
import static A.DEBUG;

public class B {
  public void myMethod() {
    if (DEBUG) {
      // do something
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I know we're not supposed to do "thank you" comments. But awesome! That's the way to keep in a single location the debug flag value and use around the application. Then, with one line change you can compile a production version. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are in front of a `public static field`, look in `import` list and pick the original class or, use the inline help from Eclipse as said in comments

Comment: I tested creating `public static final boolean DEBUG` in class1.java and in class2.java importing class1.java and use DEBUG, but unless I write class1.DEBUG it won't recognise. It's probably something on the project configuration. I know on the TexasInstrument IDE for their microcontrolers there's a section you can declare constants, but that's C for embed uC

Comment: @Budius You are right, then verify if your class extends anotehr class (or an abstract)

Comment: that's something I saw on GitHub or google.code and always bugged me. I remembered now, asked some ppl around work, no one knows. But at least now is registered and next time I see one I'll check out the project, dig into it and post the answer back in here.

Comment: @Budius I saw also it in an old version of an OODB src. I'm quite certain it is bound to inheritence. As I use log4j, I've forgotten this way of codding - As you, if I found something about this, I'll post here